# Yii missing file after send via form

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2

i'm new in phbp and yii and i have a pronblem with sendind file, i'm using kartik\file\FileInput widget without model and i send to yii controller, where i can get my file from $POST and in first time i used move_uploaded_file with linkt to my file on tmp. The first idea with move doesnt work, i wouldnt find my file on disk, i know is systemd, but i change my tmp folder in php.ini but the file from form doesnt show in this place. This is my conbtroller

```
    $output = "";
    $modelZalaczniki = new DelegacjeZalacznikiSearch();
    $modelZalaczniki->d_add = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $modelZalaczniki->u_add = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;

    if (empty($_FILES['file'])){
        echo json_encode(['error'=>'Nie znaleziono plik.w.']);
        return;
    }

    $files = $_FILES['file'];
    $success = null;
    $paths = [];

    $fileNames = $files['name'];

    if(!file_exists('uploads')){
        mkdir('uploads', 0750, true);
    }
    if(!file_exists('uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'delegacje')){
        mkdir('uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'delegacje', 0750, true);
    }
    if(!file_exists('uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'delegacje'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'pliki')){
        mkdir('uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'delegacje'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'pliki', 0750, true);
    }
    if(!file_exists('uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'delegacje'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'pliki'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$delegacja_id)){
        mkdir('uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'delegacje'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'pliki'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$delegacja_id, 0750, true);
    }
    for($i = 0; $i < count($fileNames); $i++){
        $ext = explode('.', basename($fileNames[$i]));
        $hashName = md5($fileNames[$i]);
        $target = 'uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'delegacje'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'pliki'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$delegacja_id.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$hashName;
        // if(file_exists($target)){
        //     $success = true;
        //     break;
        // }

        if(move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'][$i], $target)){
            $success = true;
            $paths[] = $target;

            $modelZalaczniki = new DelegacjeZalaczniki();
            $modelZalaczniki->delegacja_id = $delegacja_id;
            $modelZalaczniki->d_add = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $modelZalaczniki->u_add = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
            $modelZalaczniki->sciezka = $target;
            $modelZalaczniki->nazwa = $fileNames[$i];
            $modelZalaczniki->typ = $ext[1];
            $modelZalaczniki->size = $files['size'][$i];

            if ($modelZalaczniki->validate()){
                $modelZalaczniki->save();
            }
        }else{
            $success = false;
            break;
        }
```

Every things work fine but i cant move file to my folder, aha, file is create but in this file is linkt to yii documentation.

Comment: I must add some things i would like to send file without using a model, is it  feasible ?

Comment: there isnt any point of using Yii if you code like this , you should utilize the framework if you want to work **in the framework**, you should use the `yii\web\UploadedFile` as described here in the article https://yii2-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/input-file-upload/

Answer (score 0):

Yii 2.0 is great at uploading files. No need for `move_uploaded_file`.

Take a look at the documentation, and specifically the `UploadedFile::getInstance()` method.

Useful examples which are relevant to what you're doing are here:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload

> In the above code, when the form is submitted, the yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance() method is called to represent the uploaded file as an UploadedFile instance. We then rely on the model validation to make sure the uploaded file is valid and save the file on the server.